# ServletException : Property 'activeDate' not indexed

Tags: jsp, struts

```
<td class="colourSectionField" colspan="3">
    <c:set var="tabIndex" value="${tabIndex + 1}"/>
    <html:select property="activeDate[1]" tabindex="${tabIndex}" disabled="${userRole == '1'}" styleClass="${userRole == '1' ? 'colourSectionTextFieldDisabled' : 'colourSectionTextField'}">
        <html:option value="">---</html:option>
        <html:options collection="shortMonthsList" property="value" labelProperty="label"/>
    </html:select>&nbsp;
    <c:set var="tabIndex" value="${tabIndex + 1}"/>
    <html:select property="activeDate[2]"  tabindex="${tabIndex}" disabled="${userRole == '1'}" styleClass="${userRole == '1' ? 'colourSectionTextFieldDisabled' : 'colourSectionTextField'}">
        <html:option value="">--</html:option>
        <c:forEach varStatus="dd" begin="1" end="31">
            <c:set var="d"><fmt:formatNumber value="${dd.index}" pattern="00"/></c:set>
            <html:option value="${d}"/>
        </c:forEach>
    </html:select>&nbsp;
    <c:set var="tabIndex" value="${tabIndex + 1}"/>
    <html:text property="activeDate[0]"  tabindex="${tabIndex}" disabled="${userRole == '1'}" styleClass="${userRole == '1' ? 'colourSectionTextFieldDisabled' : 'colourSectionTextField'}" size="4" maxlength="4"/>
</td>
```

I am getting the following error in JSP page whenever my application is executed javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ServletException : Property 'activeDate' not indexed. How to resolve this issue ?

When the specific application deployed in Tomcat (8) shows up error and loads the page, same war when deployed in websphere showing same error and not loading the page

Comment: Show the stacktrace of the error (see log files), and **your code**, too.

Comment: And the code of `member_details.jsp`? We don't have a crystal ball.

Comment: Details should be added to the question, not wedged into comments, where they're difficult to read. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page; you need to provide all relevant details.

Comment: I deleted my answer relating to WEB-INF, as the added information seems to be a different issue.